# How to import node module in typescript project. ERR_REQUIRE_ESM

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I am trying to import the package p-limit into my typescript project. When trying to run the project using `tsc && node serve.js`, I run into the error below.

Im stuck at this for a few hours now...

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /project/node_modules/p-limit/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /project/node_modules/p-limit/index.js from /project/dist/services/file.ts is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /project/node_modules/p-limit/package.json.
```

This piece of code in `file.ts` is causing the issue:

```js
import pLimit from 'p-limit';
const limit = pLimit(1);
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "express"
    ],
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "files": [
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/p-limit/index.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Node version: v14.18.0

Comment: In your tsconfig you have module as commonjs. try `"module": "es2017",`

Comment: When I do this, I must also remove `"resolveJsonModule": true`, because these are conflicting. 

After doing that, on building, I get errors like: `node_modules/@types/mongodb/index.d.ts:46:78 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'bson'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?`

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

p-limit 4.0.0 and above are now ESM only. You can downgrade p-limit to 3.1.0 which is commonjs and it should work fine.

> This package is now pure ESM. Please read this.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-limit/releases/tag/v4.0.0

Alternatively you can switch your project from CJS to ESM, but that's a larger issue.

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: @ArrH why not? Seems right on target to me, I was looking for exactly the same thing

Comment: This is a workaround for the specific problem, but not for the title of the question.

Answer (score -5):

add

```json
"lib": [
    "es2017"
]
```

to your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Unfortunately still exactly the same error as my initial post